# How to get content of .txt file using FTPClient

Tags: java, ftp-client

I want to ask how to get content of .txt file using FTPClient in Java. I'd made just this but i don't know what to make now.

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.login("name", "pass");
ftpClient.connect("host");
InputStream s = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("file.txt");
//Data censored
```

I need to get content from file to string variable.
Thanks for future answers.

Answer (score 2):

For example like this

```
FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
ftpClient.login("name", "pass");
ftpClient.connect("host");
InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream("file.txt");
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
IOUtils.copy(inputStream, writer, encoding);
String contentString = writer.toString();
```

or

```
String contentString = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, encoding);
```

Very useful https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html

Jars to download are here https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi - it depends on which java you use.

If you are using maven then add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: i want to ask what version of commons_net should i import